# How to get absolute paths for FILE-Object

Tags: typo3, typoscript

in a TYPO3-Template, I am inserting images using the following code:

```
page.10.marks{
  GRAFIK-LINKS = IMAGE
  GRAFIK-LINKS.file = fileadmin/images/header-a.png
}
```

Now, this runs fine as long as I do not use speaking URLs, but when enabling extensions such as RealURL or CoolURI, the images are no longer shown. Problem is that the generated HTML refers to these images using relative paths:

```
<img xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="520" height="180" border="0" alt="" src="fileadmin/images/header-a.png" />
```

which is then translated to `http://example.com/speaking-URL/in-deep-path/fileadmin/images/header-a.png` and not found there :(

How can I get TYPO to use absolute references here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
config.absRefPrefix = /
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need absolute Links, you should set a **base-Tag** to handle relative links.

Example:

```
config.baseURL = http://www.yourdomain.tld/
```

Documentation:

- [TSref](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.6.0/view/1/6/#id825230)
- [RealURL Wiki](http://wiki.typo3.org/Realurl/manual#TypoScript_configuration)

Comment: You should not use ``baseUrl``, because it creates lots of trouble. Use ``config.absRefPrefix`` instead.

Comment: @pgampe Which trouble? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks to both of you - but it had set baseUrl before and then learned about absRefPrefix which solved the problem. As I also wrote in my reply above ;)

Comment: You get problems with ``realurl`` and also you might get interlink problems. In general, you should use absolute paths in URLs unless there is a good reason to use relativ paths.